# How to send a variable value with HREF in PHP

Tags: php

i have one table in locallhost ,In my table there is an item id,Now I want to send the id Related row to another page by clicking on EDIT . Thankful

The part of the program I think is difficult to write below

....
....

```
         $response["travel"]=array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        // Print out the contents of the entry 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $i . '</td>';

        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['companyname'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['cod'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['bigan'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['stop'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['time'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['price'] . '</td>';

        echo  '<td class="text-center">' .'<a href="edituser.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">EDIT</a>' .'</td>'; 




        $i++;
```

.......
.....

Comment: Where do you set `$id`? Should that be `$row['id']`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `<?php` inside strings, you use that when you've gone back into HTML mode. You should just concatenate the variable, like you do everywhere else

```
    echo  '<td class="text-center">' .'<a href="edituser.php?id=' . $id . '">ویرایش</a>' .'</td>';
```

Comment: As Barmar stated: either use PHP to concatenate the string and echo it or go back to HTML (by closing your PHP tag) and use <a href=".......?id=<?php echo $variable; ?>">Link</a> .... Recommend to use the concatenation method. I personally store the row in a single variable and then output that in 1 echo. up to you.

Comment: I also used the following code but did not work again...   echo  '<td class="text-center">' .'<a href="edituser.php?id=' . $id . '">ویرایش</a>' .'</td>'; .....But if I enter the number myself, it works like this.. echo  '<td class="text-center">' .'<a href="edituser.php?id=23' . $id . '">ویرایش</a>' .'</td>';.........I do not know where I'm making a mistake
Thanks again for the good friends

Comment: Have you assigned `$id`?